# Playing an audio file using discord.js and ytdl-core

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to download and play an audio file fetched from youtube using ytdl and discord.js:

```
        ytdl(url)
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./music/downloads/music.mp3'));

        var voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;
        voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
            console.log("joined channel");
            const dispatcher = connection.playFile('./music/downloads/music.mp3');
            dispatcher.on("end", end => {
                console.log("left channel");
                voiceChannel.leave();
            });
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
        isReady = true
```

I successfully manage to play the mp3 file in ./music/downloads/ without the ytdl part (`ytdl(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./music/downloads/music.mp3'));`). But when that part is in the code, the bot just joins and leaves.

Here is the output with the ytdl part:

```
Bot has started, with 107 users, in 43 channels of 3 guilds.
joined channel
left channel
```

And here is the output without the ytdl part:

```
Bot has started, with 107 users, in 43 channels of 3 guilds.
joined channel
[plays mp3 file]
left channel
```

Why is that and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [playStream](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=playStream) instead of playFile when you need to play a audio stream.

```
const streamOptions = { seek: 0, volume: 1 };
var voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;
        voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
            console.log("joined channel");
            const stream = ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOMhN-hfMtY', { filter : 'audioonly' });
            const dispatcher = connection.playStream(stream, streamOptions);
            dispatcher.on("end", end => {
                console.log("left channel");
                voiceChannel.leave();
            });
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Is there any way to be able to watch the video by changing the  `filter : 'audioonly'`?

Answer (score 1):

> You're doing it in an inefficient way. There's no synchronization between reading and writing. 
>  Wait for the file to be written to the filesystem, then read it!

## Directly stream it

Redirect **YTDL**'s video output to dispatcher, which would be converted to `opus` audio data packets first, then streamed from your computer to Discord.

```js
message.member.voiceChannel.join()
.then(connection => {
    console.log('joined channel');

    connection.playStream(ytdl(url))
    // When no packets left to send, leave the channel.
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log('left channel');
        connection.channel.leave();
    })
    // Handle error without crashing the app.
    .catch(console.error);
})
.catch(console.error);
```

## FWTR (First write, then read)

The approach you used wass pretty close to success, but the failure is when you don't synchronize read/write.

```
var stream = ytdl(url);

// Wait until writing is finished
stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('tmp_buf_audio.mp3'))
.on('end', () => {
    message.member.voiceChannel.join()
    .then(connection => {
        console.log('joined channel');

        connection.playStream(fs.createReadStream('tmp_buf_audio.mp3'))
        // When no packets left to send, leave the channel.
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log('left channel');
            connection.channel.leave();
        })
        // Handle error without crashing the app.
        .catch(console.error);
    })
    .catch(console.error);
});
```